# Attempting MS Sql Server Query by TimeStamp/DateTime

Tags: timestamp

I am using MS Sql Server Mgt Studio 9.0 and attempting to get a query to filter my IISAccessLogs [dbo.IISRequests] for specific IP access attempts within a specific range.
If I query my DB with

```
select * from iisrequests where ClientIPAddress like '192.168.120.%'
or ClientIPAddress like '192.168.125.%'
```

I get a return that has all the requests in the logs from these addresses; however I want to only view recent activity within the past 14 days.

I have tried

```
select * from iisrequests where ClientIPAddress like '192.168.120.%'
or ClientIPAddress like '192.168.125.%' and TimeStamp >= '20130411
00:00:00'
```

which still gives me a return of all the logs (as did the first run) and I have tried

```
select * from iisrequests where ClientIPAddress like '192.168.120.%' or ClientIPAddress like '192.168.125.%' and DateTime >= '20130411 00:00:00'
```

which gives me an error

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Invalid
>   column name 'DateTime'.

My dbo.IISRequests shows

```
 Create Table [dbo].[IISRequests] (
 ~ (obfusicated)
[TimeStamp [datetime] NULL,
 ~ (obfusicated)
```

In the table output after query my TimeStamp column shows the dates as `2013-03-29 08:30:45.0000`

How do I get this to only return the TimeStamp activity I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select * from iisrequests 
where (ClientIPAddress like '192.168.120.%' 
    or ClientIPAddress like '192.168.125.%') 
and TimeStamp >= '2013-04-11'
```